# Problem in building war for web services

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, deployment, soap

We are involved in the development of web services and also web portal which is Java/J2EE based. Which uses tomcat6 application server. The web services are written using netbeans IDE and the web portal is written using Eclipse IDE. We have development and deployment web java/j2ee web portals before.We used create a web archive file in eclipse, select the project->right click and export the file in WAR format and used to copy the war file to tomcat6/webapps folder and tomcat6 server would unwar it and run, when we restarted the server, but when we got the war file from net beans which is web services, its not unwared some times, but some times it un wars but the structure will be different and few files will be missing, what would be the problem and how to we resolve.

Kindly help us

Comment: Can you please post a comparison of your folders in your war-files? maybe then we can see what's wrong. Further, I recommend to use a build manager like `maven` to work IDE independent

Comment: @powerMicha : I will post a snap shot of the project explorer and also the snap shot of the files and structure when I get the war from Netbeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the WAR file was built correctly?  Try unpacking it yourself (just rename the extension to .zip and open it) and comparing the file structure to what Tomcat unpacked.  There will probably be no difference: the war file was probably built wrong.

As sherif suggested, you could use ant to build it, or maven.  I'm not sure what netbeans uses by default.

Comment: @sherif when I generate a war file of the web services which are developed using Net beans it gives couple of folders like build, dist etc. Inside the dist folder I will get war file, if i try to deploy it it does not work well but inside the build folder there is one more folder called web which contains the all the libraries and class files. I can say its unzipped form of war, when i zip it and unzip it in the server it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

may be you can use ant ?
http://www.vaannila.com/ant/ant-sample-build-file-war-1.html

Comment: bdares:when I generate a war file of the web services which are developed using Net beans it gives couple of folders like build, dist etc. Inside the dist folder I will get war file, if i try to deploy it it does not work well but inside the build folder there is one more folder called web which contains the all the libraries and class files. I can say its unzipped form of war, when i zip it and unzip it in the server it works fine